# Redis - getting user likes for mutiple posts in a single call

Tags: redis

This is not some thing new , But not able to decide on the best approach to take for it .

It is some thing similar to facebook wall with the likes . If the logged in user is already liked the post show the like button in green color or else show it in gray color .

Here the two approaches I am thinking for now

For the 40 posts I am displaying to the user in a single view , get the Post_ids of the 40 posts and then

1) If I stored likes in SET using some thing like

**post#id:likes userid1 userid2**

I can write Lua  script to run ISMEMBER  for the above 40 post_ids and get the result to the user

2) If I store the likes in Hash using some thing like

**user#id:likes  post_Id1 1  post_id2 1 ....**

Here I am storing the liked post_id as a key in user hash set and value is some dummy value. With this approach now I can now use `HMGET user#id:likes  post_id1 post_id28 ...` to see what posts liked by the user in single command .

Can I know if there is any problem with the second approach ? It looks simple and easy . Also from this document , 
https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization 
it says

> Use hashes when possible
>
> Small hashes are encoded in a very small space, so you should try
>   representing your data using hashes every time it is possible. For
>   instance if you have objects representing users in a web application,
>   instead of using different keys for name, surname, email, password,
>   use a single hash with all the required fields.
>
> If you want to know more about this, read the next section.

Comment: That excerpt is really about hashes vs keys, I don't think it applies here. Either of these approaches would be fine for this specific use case, but you need to think about *all* your potential needs. For example, let's say one of your use cases was to find likes in common between two users. That would point to the set solution and using `SINTER`.

Comment: Thank You @KevinChristopherHenry . Your comment simplifies my answer

Comment: You also do not need a Lua script for this. You can use a pipeline that has multiple `ISMEMBER` commands instead.

Comment: thank you @TheDude . This is really helpful . I am using nodejs and I read the documents pipeline using Nodejs is very slow ( https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/539 )  , But I checked again and found there is a batch command that improved the performance . I am going to use it and see . Thank You . Please let me know in case if you have any additional comments